# Back reference data on existing collections

Tags: mongodb

I have an existing collection (5k records already in production) in mongodb like below

```
//authors collection

[{
  "name": "xyz",
  "books": [
    {
      id: "123",
      title: "some title"
    },
    {
      id: "456",
      title: "some title"
    },
    {
      id: "789",
      title: "some title"
    }    
  ]
},
{
  name: "abc",
  "books": [
    {
      id: "432",
      title: "my book"
    }
  ]
}
]


// books collection
[
  {
    id: "123",
    title: "some title",
    date: "relase date"
    edition: "4th edition"
    authors: [] //new key and need to populate this from the authors collection

  } 

   //and so on 
]
```

**In the above books collection, I need to populate authors from the 'authors' collection. It is an existing database with the above structure and has around 5k records in mongodb collection.**

Each book can have multiple authors!

What will be the most efficient way to achieve this?